# navigateToLoginRequestUrl in MSAL Config is ignored in Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

We have MSAL Configuration and `navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true`, the value is honored in Chrome browser, but in Microsoft Edge browser the value is ignored and redirecting back to value in `redirectUri`.

Could you please help me how this can be addressed in Edge browser.

Comment: Try to set `navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false` and `redirectUri: <your-login-page>`.

Comment: I don't want application to redirect to ```login-page```, I want to navigate back to same page where I was before calling B2C (I'm using ```loginRedirect()```).

Comment: I mean that if `navigateToLoginRequestUrl` doesn't work, you could use `redirectUri` to navigate to the page you want.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with `MSAL 0.2.2` version and it has been fixed in the `MSAL 0.2.3`. Please try to upgrade the MSAL version and check [issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/330) [links](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/347)  it have help you in understanding more